thymeleaf generated opengraph tags not picked up by facebook scrapper debugger
I can't seem to understand why facebook scapper debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) won't pick up the og:url and og:type tags. In fact I think it doesn't pick up any tags from this thymeleaf (4) template:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{template.html}">
<head>
    <title>hi there</title>
    <meta property="og:title" th:content="|Hello ${reportId}|" />
    <meta property="og:url" th:content="|https://www.something.com?id=${reportId}|" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Get from SEO newbie to SEO pro in 8 simple steps." />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://ahrefs.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/fb-how-to-become-an-seo-expert.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="${reportId}"></p>
</body>
</html>

this is the generated HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{template.html}">

<head>
    <title>hi there</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Hello d9e36b28-e24f-461a-a072-1130188d7554" />
    <meta property="og:url"
        content="https://www.something.com?id=d9e36b28-e24f-461a-a072-1130188d7554" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Get from SEO newbie to SEO pro in 8 simple steps." />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image"
        content="https://ahrefs.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/fb-how-to-become-an-seo-expert.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <p>d9e36b28-e24f-461a-a072-1130188d7554</p>
</body>

</html>

When running the debugger states that its missing important tags: og:url, og:type...
